# Video js can't play my m3u8 video file in Apache and Linux

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http-live-streaming, video.js, m3u8

I have problems with my local MVC application (website), I am using Lubuntu 18.04 and apache and PHP. I have m3u8 files for HTTP Live Streaming.
This is my **.htaccess** file :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8
AddType video/MP2T .ts
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(mp3|php|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ttf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|webm|txt|m3u8|ts|M3U8|TS|manifest)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE  image/jpeg
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE  image/jpg
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE  image/png
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

This is my php file for the video js hls player :

```
...
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var player = videojs('my-video');
        player.src({
          src: "<? echo $this->url('').'src/app/views/courses/0f5f49dd1829099d48105b3fee7c150e/video3.m3u8'; ?>",
          type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
        });
        player.play();
</script>
...
```

This is my console in firefox 74: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt3pX.png)

The m3u8 file is loaded in the page : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpDz1.png)

I hope that someone has the solution, thank you.

Comment: Narrow this problem down.  Does the video work locally if you play the HLS URL in VLC or something?  If you enable CORS, does the stream work from one fo the demo players, such as via HLS.js' demo page?  Also, the way you're injecting the URL into JavaScript from PHP is bound to fail at some point.  Use `json_encode()` and let it generate the necessary quoting and escaping for you, rather than simply concatenating.  Chances are, there's something wrong with your encoding, but you didn't show us that part.

Comment: @Brad 
I tried **json_encode()** and I tried to play the video URL from VLC and it is playable,
Also, I created another folder outside this project (without .htaccess file) and it is playable with video.js and hls.js.

Comment: So, why are you rewriting everything to `index.php`?

Comment: @Brad
I am using MVC pattern in this script. Do you have any suggestions for the .htaccess file.

Comment: Yeah... don't use it for your media files!  Surely you don't want to route *everything* to `index.php`.

Comment: Is the browser running on Linix too? Make sure it has h264 codec support installed, it won't be by default on all distros.